# I am not able to launch main activity while provisioning device

Tags: java, android

**This is my AdminReceiver**

```
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    private final String TAG = MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class.getName();
```

this method is not calling from receiver ....

```
    @Override
    public void onProfileProvisioningComplete(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        super.onProfileProvisioningComplete(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PersistableBundle extras = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE);
            Log.d(TAG, "onProfileProvisioningComplete Extras:" + extras.getString("id"));
            Toast.makeText(context, "Provision", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent launch = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            launch.putExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE, extras);
            launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(launch);
    }

    public static ComponentName getComponentName(Context context) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "receive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class);

    }
```

This method is called but onProfileComplete is no calling I was trying every possibilities
but isn't work please help...

```
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
//        Intent launch = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
//        launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//        context.startActivity(launch);

//        PersistableBundle extras = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Toast.makeText(context, action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE.equals(action)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "hahha", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not able to launch main activity